# Which header in request shows remote client's IP address

Tags: http

I am trying to get the IPV4 address of the user trying to access a web server using the request object. Which header stores the IPV4 address of the requester?
I tried these headers but all have blank values.

```
    HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR
    Remote_Addr
    HTTP_CLIENT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HTTP_CLIENT_IP
HTTP_X_FORWARDED
HTTP_FORWARDED
```

Comment: None worked. Does the request always have the IP where it is coming from?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!